# How to make private python methods the last company-mode choices?

Tags: python, completion, company-mode, sorting

I'm using emacs with company-mode and I'd like the 'private' methods (method that start with underline) to be shown last, since they are kind of useless for imported libraries in python. See the image:
[image: underline methods]

I'd like it to be sorted like this:
[image: desired way]

Comment: Have you looked into `company-transformers`? Looks like what you want could be achieved by setting this to a function of your own. On the other hand, this is something more people should want, so there's likely an easier way.

Comment: Well I don't know elisp but I spent an hour hacking around anaconda functions and I managed to remove the underline methods. When I have the time I'll try to push them at the end of the list. I'll also take a look at this function you mentioned and share the code once it's ready. Thanks

Comment: @MeaningfulUsername done with company-transformers. Thanks again!

Comment: No problems, just happened to stumble over that variable some days ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've managed to do it myself. Here's the code

```
(defun company-transform-python (candidates)
  (let ((deleted))
    (mapcar #'(lambda (c)
        (if (or (string-prefix-p "_" c) (string-prefix-p "._" c))
            (progn
              (add-to-list 'deleted c)
              (setq candidates (delete c candidates)))))
        candidates) 
    (append candidates (nreverse deleted))))


(defun my-python-conf()
  (setq-local company-transformers
          (append company-transformers '(company-transform-python))))

(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'my-python-conf)
```

It's kind of my first contact more deeply with elisp, so please excuse the bad code.

Comment: You might want to consider setq-local in `my-python-config`. In that way it will only affect python buffers. In this way I believe it will overwrite the global company-transformers. You might want to add it to the list too instead of disregarding the previous value. Just some thoughts :).

Comment: @MeaningfulUsername done :)

Comment: The built-in `string-prefix-p` does what your `string/starts-with` does.

Comment: @erikstokes nice! I updated the code. Thanks

Comment: You can remove the `(setq deleted '())` since let variables are initialized to `nil` by default (and `nil` is identical to `'()`)

Comment: @alexmurray edited. Thanks for the hint :)

Answer (score 1):

The following has worked well for me:

```el
(defun python--private-lessp (x y)
  (cond
   ((and (string-prefix-p "_" x)
         (not (string-prefix-p "_" y))) nil)
   ((and (string-prefix-p "_" y)
         (not (string-prefix-p "_" x))) t)
   (t (string-lessp x y))))

(defun company-transform-python (candidates)
  "De-prioritize internal/private Python variables (e.g. 
  'var._blah') in completion list ordering.

  See `company-transformers'."
  (seq-sort-by 'company-strip-prefix 'python--private-lessp
               candidates))

(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'company-transform-python)
(add-hook 'inferior-python-mode-hook 'company-transform-python)
```