# Adaptive sorting of a company backends results

Tags: company-mode

Is there a way of asking `company` to sort the results it shows based on past choices? The custom variable `company-transformers` controls this behaviour. The only built-in choices are `company-sort-by-occurrence` and `company-sort-by-backend-importance`. Is there an existing method, possibly from another package, that I could use to do adaptive filtering of these results?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[company-statistics](https://github.com/company-mode/company-statistics) should solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Besides company-statics, you can also write functions to do the sorting yourself, and then you add the function to the variable `company-transformers`. I did this for sorting python private methods last, see: [How to make private python methods the last company-mode choices?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12360/how-to-make-private-python-methods-the-last-company-mode-choices)