# Get company to sort single underscore before double underscore, specifically with elpy/python-mode

Tags: elpy, sorting, company

Edit: this question is a duplicate of [this one](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12360/how-to-make-private-python-methods-the-last-company-mode-choices); I'm leaving it because I got a helpful answer and I didn't find the other one after reasonable amount of searching (so I hope this one being here will double the liklihood of future searchers finding a solution)

I use elpy with elpy-module-company as one of its modules.  when I type
"`self._`", the sorting causes it to propose all the dunders (`__annotations__`, `__class__`, &c) that I don't usually care about.

[image]

I name some attributes starting with single underscore.  I would like to see `self._method_i_wrote` sort before `self.__annotations__`

I see that maybe `company-sort-predicate` is what I want, but I don't know
how to write the predicate or tell company to use it.  Can anyone give an example?

I think hooking in the sort predicate I could figure out, but defining the sort predicate is beyond my elisp powers.

An i-could-live-with-it solution (for what is admittedly a first world problem) would be a filter that tosses out dunders completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find what you are looking for here: [How to make private python methods the last company-mode choices?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12360/how-to-make-private-python-methods-the-last-company-mode-choices)

Here is a way I got strings to sort the way you described:

```
(sort '("_two" "_one" "__two" "__one" "one")
      (lambda (s1 s2)
    (if (and (string-prefix-p "_" s1)
         (string-prefix-p "_" s2))       
        ;; sort _ words by number of leading _, then lexically
        (let ((n1 (progn (string-match "\\(^_+\\)" s1)
                 (length (match-string 0 s1))))
          (n2 (progn (string-match "\\(^_+\\)" s2)
                 (length (match-string 0 s2)))))
          (if (= n1 n2)
          ;; sort lexically
          (string< (substring s1 n1) (substring s2 n2))
        ;; else by number of _
        (< n1 n2)))
      ;; regular sorting          
      (string< s1 s2))))
```

This outputs `("_one" "_two" "__one" "__two" "one")`

Comment: Thank you.  My question should get marked as a duplicate.  Your sort logic will be helpful I think, I haven't gotten company to use it yet.